# Select and count in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a relationship like States with cities (where cities get added from time to time). I wish to make a query specification to retrieve all states and the current number of cities it has. Ideally in the same query and as efficient as possible.

I Say specification because I wish to combine it with other specifications in different parts of the project.

Normally I would make a derived attribute with triggers in my database, but portability is a concern. What are my options for doing that in my Spring application without compromising efficiency to much?

Since I em pretty new to Spring I thought of doing a query for states and then count cities in a foreach loop, but there surely is a better alternative.

Comment: please share your code you have tried so far. it may be helpful.

Comment: before asking a questions at stackoverflow, is better to try code your self then if there is any error or issue, please share that code.

Answer (score 1):

In your `StateEntity` you can use `@Formula` plus subquery to get the cities number.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="state")
public class StateEntity

    @Id
    @Column(name="state_id")
    private int id;

    ....
    @Formula(" (select count(*) from city c where c.state_id=state_id ")
    public int citiesCount;
```

Here I supposed that you have a table `city` with column `state_id` referencing `state` table primary key `state_id`

UPDATE:
Actually it's converted in SQl like this

```
select
  state_id,
  ... some more columns
  (select count(*) from city c where c.state_id=state_id) as cities_count
from
... all the conditions and joins here...
```

So I think there will be just one big select with a subselects for each state you got in the results.

If you sometimes need and sometimes don't need the count you can define two classes `StateEntity` and `StateEntityWithCount extends StateEntity`. The count column with formula can be added to the StateEntityWithCount . Depending on whether you need the count you can use corresponding entity class.

About portability you are right. In common case it's true. The SQL is not portable but the SQL is standard and the expression is supported in most RDBMS as far as I know. Second, do you really need to change DB? What is probability of the change?

Finally. You can write a separate query (HQL based) to retrieve the city counts for each state you pass. That's also possible solution. See [here an example](http://www.dineshonjava.com/2012/05/hql-group-by-clause-example.html)

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your reply.

I have come across this solution while researching and, even though it looks quite like what I want, I have two concerns:
 - 1 Efficiency. Using this solution will tell spring to make an additional query for every `StateEntity` I fetch. Is there a way to tell spring I do not always want this `citiesCount` subquery to execute?
 - Second would be portability. Now I am uncertain if this is true, but I thought that using explicit SQL queries in spring would cause the loss of database portability. Is this not the case here? Or am I generally wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You want to build an HQL query, something like this:

```
select state_id, state_name, count(city_id)
from states
group by state_id, state_name
```

Then you can extract the results by writing something like this:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
  Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
  session.beginTransaction();

  String SQL_QUERY = "select state_id, state_name, count(city_id)
                      from states
                      group by state_id, state_name ";

  Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);

  for(Iterator it=query.iterate();it.hasNext();)
  {
   Object[] row = (Object[]) it.next();
   System.out.print("State Name: " + row[1]);
   System.out.println(" | Number of Cities: " + row[2]);
  }
  session.getTransaction().commit();
  session.close();
```